# jQuery count for dragging and dropping

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, count

I am using the below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hP3jc/

I need to somehow figure out a counter to tell me how many/which red blocks are placed on the which grey boxes below (as the grey boxes will be representing a value)

Any help /input will be much appreciated!

---

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hP3jc/1/ (includes an example counter template for count to increment 1 and go down by 1. All i need is coding now.

Comment: can you describe it in more details? It looks like it's not going be just one counter?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hP3jc/1/

I haveupdated it with what i would expect the count to be. I would like it so if the red blocks are placed onto the corresponding grey box, the counter would go up 1 and when removed would go down 1.

Comment: Didn't what i gave you earlier work out?

Comment: I tried using your technique but couldnt code it. Didn't work out how i thought only because I'm not great at jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have part of it now.

```
        $('.selector1, .selector2, .selector3, .selector4, .selector5').droppable({
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass(ui.draggable.attr("class"));
                CountClasses($(this));
            }
        });
    function CountClasses($this) {
        var classes = $this.attr("class").split(" ");
        var count = 0;
        var t = 0;

        for (t = 0; t < classes.length; t++)
        {
            if (classes[t].substring(0, 6) == "option") {
                count++;
            }
        }
        alert(count);
    }
```

This should serve as a starting point for you.

Now, all you need to do, is when you pick up a red box, remove its class from all .selector boxes.  You can use a simple jQuery selector to find all selector boxes with that class.

```
$(".selector.option1").each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass(".option1");
});
```

I think the above should work though it's untested.

Does this make some sense?

**edit**

Add this to your `.draggable({` code to get the class of the red box.  This is where the code should go to remove that class from all .selector boxes.

```
start: function () {  alert( $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]) }
```

**edit 2**

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

This shows you how to select on a partial name.

so `$("div[class^="selector"].optionX").each....`

very untested but looks close

Comment: Thanks for that information, it makes sense..wil play around with it now. Appreciate the time and effort.